# How do I create a yang file from sample cfg file using python?

Tags: python

```
#input:-
log.use.syslog=no


#output:-
#need help on the python to convert the cfg to yang like below
```

> module demo {
>
> yang-version 1;
>
> namespace
>       "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:demo";   prefix dm`enter code here`;   revision 2018-09-28;   container settings {
>               config true;
>           leaf log.use.syslog {
>             type string;
>           }   }  // container setting }  // module demo